# Taxonomy list custom, unique link with a field

Tags: hyperlink, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I've created a list of events with a taxonomy/vocabulary, where the 2 most recent will display on the home page and an events page lists all the events.  This works great.

However, I would like to create a link to an external site where a user can get more information on the event.  I've set up a field in the taxonomy where we can enter the URL for the event. I would like to have the event name then link to this URL.  I am trying to make this so someone who does not know how to code could maintain this site.

I've tried searching for an answer on how to do this. I may not have the correct words in my string to find the right help.

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 7 has facility to add field in taxonomy

1)install link module in drupal 7

2)Created link field in drupal 7 to stored link of external url

3)Used views to list the event name and their external url.